# amqsbcg not getting messages from MQ Client

Tags: ibm-mq

I managed to send a message from an MQ Client to a MQ Server. In the MQ Client I `amqsputc [queue_local] [name_qmgr]` and after typing the message it return `Sample AMQSPUT0 end` which means it was sent properly. But when I try to see the message in the MQ Server with `amqsbcg [queue_local] [name_qmgr]` it throws me an error message:

```
Sample AMQSGET0 start
MQCONNX ended with reason code 2058
```

This error appears when the queue manager doesn't exist or when the name is misspelled, but this is not the case.

When I verify the local queue it shows `CURDEPTH(1)`, this means that there is one message on the queue(it was delivered). But I don't know why it doesn't allow me to get the message. In the queue manager error file it only shows something like:

```
the channel AMQ.... connection ended
```

I checked the channel I configured for this test:

```
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
CHANNEL(A03ZCIWAS)                      CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
ALTDATE(2017-09-07)                     ALTTIME(00.35.17)
CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
COMPMSG(NONE)                        
DESCR(Server-connection to ...)
DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(100)
MAXINSTC(90)                            MAXMSGL(4194304)
MCAUSER(nobody)                         MONCHL(QMGR)
RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
TRPTYPE(TCP)                         
AMQ8414: Display Channel details.
CHANNEL(A03ZCIWAS)                      CHLTYPE(CLNTCONN)
AFFINITY(PREFERRED)                     ALTDATE(2017-09-07)
ALTTIME(02.40.42)                       CERTLABL( )
CLNTWGHT(0)                             COMPHDR(NONE)
COMPMSG(NONE)                           CONNAME(XX.XX.XX.XX)
DEFRECON(NO)                         
DESCR(Client connection to ....)
HBINT(300)                              KAINT(AUTO)
LOCLADDR( )                             MAXMSGL(4194304)
MODENAME( )                             PASSWORD( )
QMNAME(AEDMQ03A)                        RCVDATA( )
RCVEXIT( )                              SCYDATA( )
SCYEXIT( )                              SENDDATA( )
SENDEXIT( )                             SHARECNV(10)
SSLCIPH( )                              SSLPEER( )
TPNAME( )                               TRPTYPE(TCP)
USERID( )
```

The `CONNAME(xx.xx.xx.xx)` is the right IP adress for the MQServer and the variable MQSERVER is set like:

```
MQSERVER=[channel_svrconn]/tcp/'ip_adress_MQServer(1414)'
```

The port is also fine.

Comment: Thank you @JoshMc for your help, that was the solution. I can now open the message without any problems

Comment: I noticed you have 55 questions you have asked on SO but have never accepted even one of those.  If you are not aware, you can accept one answer you feel is best for the question you asked by clicking the "check mark" that is grayed out right below the down arrow to the left of the answer.  The "check mark" will turn green indicating that you have accepted that answer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that check mark, thanks

Comment: Thank you for the accept.  Note that you can go to your profile and look at the questions tab and see wll the questions you have asked.  Each accept will give you  +2 reputation.  Just accepting answers to your older questions could give you a 100 points of rep and I'm sure would be appreciated by those that answered them who will get rep as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you provide indicates you are executing `amqsget` not `amqsbcgc`.

I note that your question mentions `amqsbcg` not `amqsbcgc`. The `c` at the end of the sample name indicates it is the *client* version of the program.

```
amqsbcg = Server Binding version
amqsbcgc = Client version
```

If you execute either `amqsget` or `amqsbcg` and specify a queue manager that is not local on the same server you will receive a `2058`.

Solution is to use `amqsgetc` or `amqsbcgc` instead of `amqsget` or `amqsbcg`

Comment: Running `amqsgetc queuename queue_manager_name` (or `amqsbcgc`) returns me `MQCONNX failed with CompCode:2, Reason:2058` error. Where as the `amqsget` and `amqsbcg` (server versions) run fine. Both are run on the local server. Why is that?

Comment: @AmitTendulkar, without the c (client version) things will work fine on a server where the queue manager exists.   With the c you will need to tell it how to connect over the network via MQSERVER env variable or a CCDT.